# How to register my app so that it appears in the phote edit list in windows phone 8.1 runtime

Tags: runtime, edit, windows-phone-8.1, photo

How can I register my windows phone 8.1 runtime app so that it appears in the poto edit list?
The only way I see is to create an app for windows phone 8.0 silverlight (there is a template in VS 2013) then edit the wmappmanifest.xml and then upgrade the project to wp81.
But I think there must be another way to achieve that directly in a wp81 runtime project.
Does anyone know how to do that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN article

[Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx)

one of the Windows Phone 8 features for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent is extending the photo edit picker.

So, in case you're building a Windows Phone WinRT app, this won't be possible.