# How to integrate my image editing app into photo's "Edit" section as an available editor in Lumia?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have an image editing app for Windows Phone 8.1. I want it to be displayed in the list of available editors, when I go to my photos' folder, select an image and press Edit. How should I do this?

P.S.I have done a "similar thing" with sharing. I added "Share Target" in Declarations tab of "**Package.appxmanifest**". When I press Share on some photo from my gallery, there is a list item with my app's name. Then I overrode "OnShareTargetActivated" in app.Xaml and did what I wanted.

Is there an analogical way of doing this with "edit" section?

Comment: I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569859/how-to-register-my-app-so-that-it-appears-in-the-phote-edit-list-in-windows-phon

It is said that it's not possible in Windows 8.1 WINRT app.
Does anyone know is it possible on Windows 10 UWP app?